# Help with VF page RemoteAction getting a List into a Set for update on SObject

Tags: controller, list, remote-action, set, service

I have custom VF page styled with JS.

The list of Ids is passed from the VF page based on what the user selects. The List is converted to a Set and The Service method should take the incoming Ids and set the custom field status__c to cancelled.

Should I be using [Set(listToCopy)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm#apex_System_Set_constructors)? I'm still learning the ropes of SF and would appreciate any help. I'm sure that pr.getParameters().put('id', classId); is not what I want to use but I'm at a loss. Thanks!

**Controller**

```
@RemoteAction
public static StudentScheduleController.ScheduleResponse withdrawClass(List<Id> classId) {
    // Verify inputs

    // Send to service
    try {
        ClassService.removeClasses(new List<Id>(classId));
        PageReference pr = Page.ClassDetail;
        pr.getParameters().put('id', classId);
        return new StudentScheduleController.ScheduleResponse(true, 'Done', pr.getUrl());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return new StudentScheduleController.ScheduleResponse(false, 'An error occurred while saving grade', null);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public without sharing class ClassService {
public static void removeClasses(List<Id> classIds) {
        // create list of ACI's to change status to canceled
        try{
            List<Student_Classes__c> classes = new List<Student_Classes__c>();
            for(Id classId: classIds) {
                classes.add(new Student_Classes__c(Id = classId, Status__c = 'Cancelled'));
            }
            update classes;

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            throw new ApplicationServiceException('Error occurred withdrawing from a class');
        }
    }
}
```

**Payload**

```
public with sharing class StudentScheduleController {
public class ScheduleResponse {
        public Boolean status;
        public String message;
        public Object payload;


        public ScheduleResponse(Boolean status, String message, Object payload) {
            this.status = status;
            this.message = message;
            this.payload = payload;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We are both at a loss. What's your actual question? What isn't working? (There's no Set<T> anywhere in your code)

Comment: I should have clarified that Set <T> is from the Developers guide for Sets [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm#apex_System_Set_constructors)

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you want to pass list of Ids to remote action method and convert that list to set.

you can convert as

```
set<Id> setIds = new set<Id>();
setids.addAll();
```

But I am not sure what you want to do with PageReference etc, can you please add your issue in more details.

Comment: I updated my comment to clarify. I also didn't realize that the getParameters() method uses a Map. Thanks for the help